# htaccess GET friendly url instead of?

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, web

I have a problem. I need to solve it. So, instead of i have to write **shop.php?id=0** I can write "shop/something". It works well but iffor example write **support/**. Then i goes to the shop php file. How can i remove this so support also can do like **support/something** and the shop also can be **shop/something**.

I can write **support**, then it works fine but when i want to do **support/something** it mess up. It's just add a "/"

How can i fix this issue?
(I've made comments with // in the code, its not in the actual code, i've removed them there)

```
RewriteEngine On
//Do so instead of i write shop.php?id=0 i can do /shop/something
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ shop.php [NC,L]

//Remove the .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

//404
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Formatted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sovled!
Really easy actually! If other might come in this case:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(shop)/([^/]*)$ /shop.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(support)/([^/]*)$ /support.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]



ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```